# [PlayFramework]Blob with @Required saves File twice

Tags: playframework, blob

Model like :

```
    @Entity
    public class Doc extends Model {
        public Blob tpl;
    }
```

Controller like:

```
    public class DocController extends Controller {
        public static void saveDoc(@Required Blob tpl){
           render();  // event no persistence operation
        }
    }
```

It will have 2 uploaded file in the data/attachments. even there are no persistence operation in the controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Doc object directly into your action (use `doc.tpl` from the view, rather than just `tpl`), and then perform the validation on the Object, rather than the Blob itself.

```
@Entity
public class Doc extends Model {
    @Required
    public Blob tpl;
}

public class DocController extends Controller {
    public static void saveDoc(@Valid Doc doc){
       render();  // event no persistence operation
    }
}
```